# What kind of regularization is $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{D}\left(\frac{w_{i}^{2}}{\lambda_{i}}+\lambda_{i}\right)$?

Tags: lasso, regularization, norm

$$\min _{\mathbf{w}} \min _{\lambda \geq 0}\left\{C \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(t_{n}-\mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{n}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{D}\left(\frac{w_{i}^{2}}{\lambda_{i}}+\lambda_{i}\right)\right\}$$

This is somehow equivalent to L1 regularization but I don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see that this is indeed equivalent to $L_1$ regularization, we can work through the calculus of the inner minimization with respect to the $\lambda_i$ for any given values of the $w_i$.  Taking the derivative of the bracketed expression with respect to an arbitrary $\lambda_i$ results in:

$${\partial (\cdot) \over \partial \lambda_i} = {1\over 2}\left(1 - {w_i^2 \over \lambda_i^2} \right)$$

which evidently equals zero when $\lambda_i = |w_i|$ (we need the $||$ due to the nonnegativity constraint on $\lambda$.)  This, combined with the fact that the second derivative is clearly positive, implies that for any collection of $w_i$, the optimum $\lambda = w$.

Substituting and eliminating the minimization with respect to $\lambda$ (which we've just done) results in:

$$\min _{\mathbf{w}} \left\{C \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(t_{n}-\mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{n}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{D}\left(\frac{w_{i}^{2}}{|w_{i}|}+|w_{i}|\right)\right\}$$

Simplifying leads to:

$$\min _{\mathbf{w}} \left\{C \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(t_{n}-\mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{n}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{D}(2|w_i|)\right\}$$

which in turn can be rearranged to  the $L_1$ penalized least squares formulation:

$$\min _{\mathbf{w}} \left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(t_{n}-\mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{n}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{C} \sum_{i=1}^{D}|w_i|\right\}$$

with $1/C$ taking the place of the more usual penalty parameter label $\lambda$.

The formulation in the question is an interesting alternative to the more usual one, albeit I can't see how it's useful in practice.

Comment: It's more obvious why the L1 norm induces sparsity in this way.

Comment: Is doing elastic net with this form useful in practice?

Comment: I wouldn't think so... it would just simplify to the usual elastic net formulation, which is reasonably well-understood computationally.

Comment: may one rewrite l2 regularization as a sum over the size of the dimension of the w vector also?